# How to render link field target attribute in rendering variant?

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.8.1 Sitecore 9.1.1.

I have a rendering variant with link wrapping a few other items (image, text etc.). I would like to pass the target attribute value which is set on the link by the editors to the variant to display something like:

```
<a href="something" target="_blank"> ... </a>
```

Is it possible to pass it through the data attributes on the link section using token or something like that? I tried using "Is Link" and without it but none of them seems to be rendering that OOTB. How can I implement it? I do not want to hardcode the _blank value (it works in this case but I need editors to be able to set it on the link item).

[image: example]

Comment: I suggest you consider an upgrade to Sitecore 9.3. You will get the ability to use Scriban templates and it will be much easier to achieve what you want.

Comment: It is planned for the future but unfortunately because of budget restrictions I need a solution right now as well. We can use NVelocity

Comment: Have you specified field "Field used as link target" on rendering variant definition? If no specify it and then just check "Is Link". It should set href to url and target should be _blank of you specify link to open in New browser window

Comment: I specified the field but it does not help much - I need to use section instead of the field because it does not pass the HTML validation otherwise. When using the section it does not pass the target value at all.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you have the field "Field used as link target" in the Variant Definition item.

[image]

Then when you select the "wrapped" option in "Is link" field for your image variant field, it will wrap your image with the link provided in the Variant Definition

[image]

And this link will have the target properties. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately inside the link I have not only the image field but also another section with div and a few different properties. I don't want to select "is link" on every property. I cannot use link field and have something nested underneath it because then I get HTML validation errors. So it seems to me that the only way to do it would be by using the section and wrap everything into "a" tag. But when I do that then the link target is not going to be set correctly. Is there any other way how it could be done?